# How to put on every page ornament symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, article

I would like to use somehow command `\eachpageornament` to place ornament border on every page of my document. I can do that using that new command on each page, but suppose our document have 200 pages, then there is problem. I found this (not exactly) code here http://altermundus.com/pages/downloads/packages/pgfornament/ornaments.pdf. It is on 12 page. On page 11 they are talking on some other solution, but I failed (because I am pretty new to LaTeX) to implement that way. You can show me that way if it is easier.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\eachpageornament}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west){%
\pgfornament[width=2cm]{63}};
\node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east){%
\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{63}};
\node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west){%
\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{63}};
\node[anchor=south east] at (current page.south east){%
\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{63}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\eachpageornament

\lipsum

\eachpageornament

\lipsum

\eachpageornament

\lipsum

\eachpageornament

\end{document}
```

You have to compile twice to see effect.

And I would like, if it is possible to do this for article A4, not scrartcl.

Comment: Have you tried the `background` or `eso-pic` packages? Do a quick search here and you will find similar questions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is MWE using the `background` and the `eso-pic`  package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Comment below if you are using the eso-pic version
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{background}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Uncomment below to obtain the same effect using the eso-pic package
%\usepackage{eso-pic}
%\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
%   \AtPageUpperLeft{\eachpageornament}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------

% Comment below if you are using the eso-pic version
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\backgroundsetup{%
contents=\eachpageornament,%
position=current page.north east,%
angle=0,%
scale=1,%
opacity=1%
}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\eachpageornament}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,color=BrickRed]
\node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west){%
\pgfornament[width=2cm]{63}};
\node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east){%
\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{63}};
\node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west){%
\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{63}};
\node[anchor=south east] at (current page.south east){%
\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{63}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

NOTE: The `pgfornament` package by Alain Matthes needs to be installed manually. [Click here](http://altermundus.com/pages/downloads/packages/pgfornament/pgfornament.zip) to download the package.

Comment: Thank you azetina. Two question: for what is `dvipsnames` and when I use second method (with `eso-pic`) I have word Draft in red color on every my page, diagonal, over my text, do you know why?

Comment: @Cortizol [`dvipsnames`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors) is used simple to change the color of the ornament to `BrickRed`. For the second example, you should not get no draft thingy. At least I don't get it in my compilation. Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, am I sure. I uncomment that part and comment `\backgroundsetup` part. But, all works well with first method (`\backgroundsetup`), so everything is ok.

Comment: @Cortizol Oh oh ok, you need to comment `\usepackage{background}` as well. The `background` package automatically place `draft` as the default background.

Comment: Exactly, now everything is working! :)

Comment: Nice. How to do this on a `mdframed` box instead on a page?

Comment: @Sigur Let me think about it but what comes to mind is using nodes on a paragraph structure.